# Como remover e renomear diretórios na linguagem C?

Tags: c, crud, sistema-de-arquivos

Para criar um diretório usei a função mkdir(const char*) e para remover tentei usar a remove(const char*),como abaixo:

```
void remove_diretorio() {
 char nome_pasta[10];
 printf("Informe o nome da pasta: ");
 fflush(stdin);
 gets(nome_pasta);
 if(remove(nome_pasta)) {
     Sleep(500);
     printf("Erro ao exlcluir o diretorio!\n");
     printf("%s",strerror(errno));
     system("pause");
     return;
 } else {
     Sleep(500);
     printf("Pasta excluída com sucesso\n");
     system("pause");
 }
}
```

Porém o retorno está sendo diferente de zero,pois está entrando no meu if. Preciso renomear também e não encontro referências.

Obs.: remove_diretorio() é uma função do meu programa; meu sistema operacional é Windows.

Comment: à parte:  esse é provavelmente um programa para uso pessoal e você não está se preocupando muito com segurança - então, ok usar o `gets` passando uma string de tamanho fixo (`char nome_pasta[10]` - (a recomendação é usar `fgets`) . No entanto, mesmo para uso pessoal, o tamanho de 10 bytes é quase CERTEZA que vai ser ultrapassado num nome de arquivo - podendo resultar no minimo no seu programa ser encerrado pelo S.O. - mas alguem conhecendo o seu programa ao digitar mais de 10 caracteres pode alterar o valor de outras variáveis internas, por exemplo. Isso seria um ataque de "buffer overrun"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu não entendo muito de C e sua arquitetura, mas sei que é bem parecido com C++, possa ser que esteja errado, mas achei esta função para excluir um diretório que não está vazio:

```
int remove_directory(const char *path)
{
   DIR *d = opendir(path);
   size_t path_len = strlen(path);
   int r = -1;

   if (d)
   {
      struct dirent *p;

      r = 0;

      while (!r && (p=readdir(d)))
      {
          int r2 = -1;
          char *buf;
          size_t len;

          /* Skip the names "." and ".." as we don't want to recurse on them. */
          if (!strcmp(p->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(p->d_name, ".."))
          {
             continue;
          }

          len = path_len + strlen(p->d_name) + 2; 
          buf = malloc(len);

          if (buf)
          {
             struct stat statbuf;

             snprintf(buf, len, "%s/%s", path, p->d_name);

             if (!stat(buf, &statbuf))
             {
                if (S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode))
                {
                   r2 = remove_directory(buf);
                }
                else
                {
                   r2 = unlink(buf);
                }
             }

             free(buf);
          }

          r = r2;
      }

      closedir(d);
   }

   if (!r)
   {
      r = rmdir(path);
   }

   return r;
}
```

([Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256945/removing-a-non-empty-directory-programmatically-in-c-or-c))

Para renomear, use a função `rename(oldFilename, newFilename)`. [Referência](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/81926-how-would-i-rename-folder.html).